# Add new language to existing Xcode project localization

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, localization

I'm working on an existing Xcode 3.2.2 Universal iPhone OS project which is already localized for 4 languages (EN, IT, DE and FR). We are now adding a new language (JA) into this project.

Each existing `.lproj` folder (`en.lproj`, `it.lproj`, `de.lproj` and `fr.lproj`) has almost 60 files - including PNGs, HTMLs and the Localizable.strings file. Each one of those files appear as localized groups inside Groups & Files in Xcode. They're spread all over the tree.

If I right-click one of those groups (say, `Localizable.strings`) inside Xcode, Get Info, click on "Add Localization" and type "`ja`" - as the Xcode docs suggest, nothing happens. From what I read in [this newgroup](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/xcode-users@lists.apple.com/msg10221.html), it's possibly because of the way those folders are named. If they were named like `English.lproj` and `Italian.lproj`, this was supposed to work.

So, for me to actually import a new language localized file into the existing group, I have to:

1. Right-click the localized group file.
2. Choose "Add Existing File".
3. Select the corresponding file inside the `ja.lproj` folder.

I'm about to get a new `ja.lproj` folder with those 60 localized files and would love to import them in the project in a way that doesn't involve searching for every single file in Groups & Trees and performing those steps... for every one of those 60 files.

Is that possible? Is there a right (or better) way to import a new language into this Xcode project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found one simple solution. After you right click any multi lingual resource file and choose |Add|Existing Files...| you can select at once all files you wish to add. After you choose the encoding, xCode will automatically add all files under the resources they should be in. I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Of course the files should be prepared inside a separate resource folder i.e. hu.proj for hungary etc.

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 7+ it's pretty simple:

1. Choose your localizable.strings file and tap on "Localize...":

[image]

2. Next window will ask you if you want the current localizable.strings file should be the default language, in my case English should be the default so I chose 'Base'
3. Choose your project from the navigation bar, choose your project again, switch to 'Info' and tap the '+' button below the Localizations title:

[image]

4. All you have to do now is to choose the langauge you want to translate and mark ONLY the Localizable.strings file:

[image]

5. Now it will be added to the Localizble.strings file and the actual string that will be shown to the user will be according to his OS language (As long as you have NSLocalizedString all over your app):

[image]

Comment: The question was about adding new languages to a project which already has many localized files (not only .strings). Does this still apply?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, by using this simple method you could avoid many issues including what you have/had.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found works:

1. click add localization;
2. replace all the files in the new .lproj folder with localized files;
3. delete the localization, and choose "keeping files";
4. done.

Answer (score 0):

The mailing list post basically sums up the issue: Xcode expects to find language bundles with names like "English.lproj", "Italian.lproj", etc. If you change those names, Xcode looses the ability to treat them as language bundles, and then you have to add files using the method you described. There's nothing wrong with how you're adding them to the project, that's just how Xcode works.

Comment: Do you know then why all the sample code use "en.lproj"? I mass added a bunch of files just by dragging all of them at once into xcode, and it put each one in the correct place, but they were all in the resources folder, and maybe I misunderstood the question...

Comment: No idea; `en.lproj` isn't necessarily incorrect, but Apple has generally encouraged using `English.lproj`, etc.

Comment: From what I understood, it's the other way around. `English.lproj` is legacy code which hasn't been fixed in Xcode yet. Apple now recommends `en.lproj`: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/10/xcode-localization-frustrations.html

Comment: I'm accepting your answer anyways as it looks like there is not other way to import those files - even if I was using the legacy `lproj` format.